# Load assets in capybara

Tags: cucumber, capybara, assets

I'm writing some acceptance tests with cucumber and capybara. When I check if an element is visible (in my css I've display:none) capybara says it is visible. I thought that assets are not loaded. How to load them with the tests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you’re running Capybara with the `rack_test` driver which doesn’t process JS at all, and only a tiny amount of inline CSS. You will need to configure Capybara to use a more full featured driver - see https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/blob/master/README.md#drivers